# tengo un problema al desplegar mi aplicación node.js y angular a heroku

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, heroku

Hola buenas tengo un problemas al desplegar a heroku un proyecto realizado en angular node js express y mysql.

ya tengo la base de datos lista y el la sección de node js me carga de hecho me carga las rutas pero solo me muestra los datos y no me manda a las vistas que realicé en angular.

he intentado muchas metodologías para conseguir mostrar las vistas de angular pero el servidor de heroku no me las muestra y me manda solo un objeto con los que contiene la base de datos.

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {



    "start": "node build/index.js"
  




  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.12",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.33",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.2",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.18",
    "angular-material": "^1.2.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mat-table-filter": "^10.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "promise-mysql": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },

  "engines": {
    "node": "16.0.0",
    "npm": "7.10.0"
  }


}
```

ese es mi archivo package.json que me carga mi index.js que es este

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const express_1 = __importDefault(require("express"));
const morgan_1 = __importDefault(require("morgan"));
const cors_1 = __importDefault(require("cors"));
const calibradoRoutes_1 = __importDefault(require("./routes/calibradoRoutes"));
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");

class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.app = express_1.default();
        this.config();
        this.routes();

     
        this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client/dist')));


        this.app.get('*', (req, res) => {

            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html'))
        });

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            this.app.use(express.static('client/dist'));
            console.log('linea 28');
        };



    }

    
    config() {
        this.app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
        this.app.use(morgan_1.default('dev'));
        this.app.use(cors_1.default());
        this.app.use(express_1.default.json());
        this.app.use(express_1.default.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


    }
    routes() {
        this.app.use('', calibradoRoutes_1.default);
    }
    start() {
        this.app.listen(this.app.get('port'), () => {
            console.log('Server on port', this.app.get('port'));
        });
    }
}





const server = new Server();
server.start();
```

si me pudieran ayuda se los agradecería mucho